# What could be a reason that I can't see any messages in the stackoveflow messages

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

What could be the reason that my inbox is empty (https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/inbox) while I receive an email. I can also reply to it. When I click on a link in the email I get page not found error. I tried incognito mode, disabled adblockers and two different browsers and on my phone.

[image]

Comment: as you say that `When I click on a link in the email I get page not found error.`

Comment: Are you logged into the same account that received the message?

Comment: yes, I have only one account, most definitely it is the same email.